# AttributeError: 'GPT4All' object has no attribute 'chat_completion'

Tags: python, gpt4all

just install gpt4all 1.0.8. Not sure how to solve this error. Thanks for help. I am using python 3.8.

https://pypi.org/project/gpt4all/

```
import gpt4all

gptj=gpt4all.GPT4All("ggml-gpt4all-j-v1.3-groovy")

messages = [{"role": "user", "content": "Give me a list of 10 colors and their RGB code"}]
ret = gptj.chat_completion(messages)
print(ret)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 2
      1 messages = [{"role": "user", "content": "Give me a list of 10 colors and their RGB code"}]
----> 2 ret = gptj.chat_completion(messages)
      3 print(ret)

AttributeError: 'GPT4All' object has no attribute 'chat_completion'
```

Comment: I don't see that method in the [docs](https://docs.gpt4all.io/gpt4all_python.html#gpt4all.gpt4all.GPT4All)?

Comment: Thank you SuperStomer. Yes look like that method of chat_completion is removed already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the API has been updated. Try

```
from gpt4all import GPT4All
model = GPT4All("add model location")
output = model.generate("The capital of France is ", max_tokens=3)
print(output)
```

output

```
1. Paris
```